# unable to install any pkg in Octave

Tags: octave

I am new to Octave, coming from Matlab. I am trying to install a few packages, and so far none has worked. I have tried the download method from forge, then running the `install` command. But my question is about my latest attempt. There it is:

```
pkg install -global -forge io
csvconcat.cc:79:37: warning: result of comparison of constant 18446744073709551615 with expression of type
      'unsigned int' is always true [-Wtautological-constant-out-of-range-compare]
          while ((pos=str.find(prot, pos)) != str.npos) {
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
error: couldn't append to /Applications/Octave-4.4.1.app/Contents/Resources/usr/Cellar/octave-octave-app@4.4.1/4.4.1/share/octave/octave_packages
save: unable to open output file '/Applications/Octave-4.4.1.app/Contents/Resources/usr/Cellar/octave-octave-app@4.4.1/4.4.1/share/octave/octave_packages'
error: called from
    install at line 254 column 7
    pkg at line 437 column 9
```

Couldn't find any documentation on it, I am a bit lost.... (oh and btw, I can't find the config.log file! where is that gem?)

I am on MacOS catalina 10.15.7, and just followed that procedure https://flaviocopes.com/fix-xcrun-error-invalid-active-developer-path/, which solved the issues I had before which is described on that page.

cheers for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error:

```
error: couldn't append to /Applications/Octave-4.4.1.app/Contents/Resources/usr/Cellar/octave-octave-app@4.4.1/4.4.1/share/octave/octave_packages
save: unable to open output file '/Applications/Octave-4.4.1.app/Contents/Resources/usr/Cellar/octave-octave-app@4.4.1/4.4.1/share/octave/octave_packages'
error: called from
    install at line 254 column 7
    pkg at line 437 column 9
```

basically says it's failing to save to that file. Probably a permissions issue.  Check if the file `/Applications/Octave-4.4.1.app/Contents/Resources/usr/Cellar/octave-octave-app@4.4.1/4.4.1/share/octave/octave_packages` exists and its permissions.  That file is a database of all packages installed globally, i.e., for all users in the system.

Fixing the permission issues is dependent on what is the permissions issue you have (probably you need to run octave as root to install a global package). But maybe try to install the package for your user only, i.e., install the package without the `-global` flag, like so:

```
pkg install -forge io
```